# Testing for file changed inside trigger

Tags: triggers, clearcase

I'm integrating clearcase with internal project management tool. I want to call a REST URL after all checkin that match a certain comment pattern.

I achive that using CURL in a trigger after checkin proccess and it's OK.

My question is how to determine if the resource was modified inside my trigger script? I need to prevent calling integration if the user is checkin a unmodified file.

Does anyone knows if clearcase provide me that status inside some variable or do I have some way to detect that?

Thank you and sorry by the english

Answer (score 0):

If your trigger has access to what has been checked in (typically, the variable `$CLEARCASE_XPN` should be set), you can do a:

```
cleartool diff -pred "$CLEARCASE_XPN"
```

If the diff is empty, that means there has been a `cleartool checkin -identical` (which is one way of creating a version identical to the previous version of an element)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, diff only works with "diff-able" element types (ASCII, XML,..).

If you also have to do that with other element types (binary) I have a suggestion:
- use an attribute "checksum" that is attached on each version
- on pre-checkin (in your case after the checkiin) you calculate a new checksum all over the content of the new version
- you update the attribute on the new version and compare the checksum with the value of the attribute of the predecessor
- if the values are different something has really changed

Hope that helps..